# I'm looking for a site, similar to StackOverflow, but with possibility to ask opinion based questions

Tags: discussion

Since opinion based questions are not allowed neither here nor on stackoverflow, I would like to ask if any of you, know some other web page (outside Stack* ecosystem), where we can ask questions like:

"Which Java Web framework would you recommend to learn"

or any other, which by nature are opinion based.

EDIT1:

Allow me to explain a bit more - I know there are webgroups, forums and mailing lists BUT most of those are for single programming language or framework and I'm looking for something more generic. Stackoverflow is great because there are experts from all sort of programming languages and frameworks, so if it would be allowed to ask:

"Best web frameworks similar to ASP.NET MVC4"

I would get a lot of opinions, from different languages and frameworks, and that exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: They're called forums or newsgroups, and have been around for decades - in fact, StackOverflow pretty much came up as a *reaction* to those forums. However, you probably won't find forums that cover the entire range of StackOveflow, and would probably need to be more specific of the technologies that interest you.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan:

Sure I can go to Java forum and ask some questions, and http://asp.net is good place to ask about .NET... BUT I'm looking for something more generic, stackoverflow is great because there are experts from all sort of programming languages and frameworks, so if it would be allowed to ask: "Best web frameworks similar to ASP.NET MVC4", I would get a lot of opinions, from different languages and frameworks, and that exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Quora. [They loves them some opinions!](http://www.quora.com/Web-Application-Frameworks/Which-is-the-best-Web-Application-Framework-to-start-with-if-I-know-PHP-Ruby-Java-and-Python)

Not gonna vouch for the validity of those opinions, but if you're willing to log in they'll often make up for any perceived lack of quality in sheer volume. A killer deal, if I do say so!

Comment: Looks interesting, thank You.

Comment: Golly, that sure is a lot of opinions people have!

Comment: Their mods never believe me that my real name is Seamus LeFrankfurter, though.

Comment: [Slant - discover da best!](http://www.slant.co/)